# Shorten the NTP service startup time under no network

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I need to create an NTPServer for the MCU without battery to calibrate the time information, I want to calibrate as soon as possible after power on.

When I am in a local area network without a network, after the NTPServer starts, I need to wait about five minutes to synchronize the time with other computers. How can I modify it to use NTP to synchronize in real time without waiting for 5~17 minutes?

I tried to modify Minpoll and maxpoll, but it still took about 5 minutes to initialize in an environment without a network.

How to shorten NTP Server Init time?

Answer (score 0):

`ntpd` needs to make multiple requests to a NTP server before it can have a firm idea of its reliability and the communications latency. Normally `ntpd` will make requests only once per poll interval, which is initially determined by the `minpoll` value, and is normally one poll in 64 seconds.

By adding the `iburst` option to your NTP time source definitions, it allows `ntpd` to ignore the `minpoll` value when it's starting up, which allows the initial synchronization to be established much faster - or a much faster retry cycle when the time source is actually unreachable.

Syntax:

```
server <NTP server hostname or IP> iburst
pool <NTP server pool DNS name> iburst
peer <NTP peer hostname or IP> iburst
```

If you aren't already using the `iburst` option, adding it is probably the most effective way to shorten the startup time of `ntpd`.